# Moodle 2.4.2 Coding Error detected when using Course Bulk upload

Tags: php, moodle

I tried course bulk upload plugin for creating courses using CSV in moodle 2.4.2.
But the course created shows error in debugging mode. Is there any solution for this issue.

```
Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: 
Invalid string compontent. Please check your string definition More information    
about this error

Debug info:
Error code:
codingerror Stack trace:

•line 11176 of \lib\moodlelib.php: coding_exception thrown

•line 812 of \lib\outputrequirementslib.php: call to lang_string->__construct()

•line 848 of \lib\outputrequirementslib.php: call to page_requirements_manager->string_for_js()

•line 4575 of \course\lib.php: call to page_requirements_manager->strings_for_js()

•line 282 of \course\view.php: call to include_course_ajax()
```

Thanks in Advance

Vinoth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error may be due to the theme section i used. I tried to use the different form of CSV only with Category, shortname, desscription, format etc. And now the courses are created successfully with no error.
It solved my problem.

Thanks
Vinoth